# request-promise not recognizing the URI when it is stated in the option object

Tags: http, request-promise

I have a method that should return a response from another server. I use request-promise and put the URL in the `options` object.

As you can see in the code below, all is in good shape, but when I send the request, it returns `404 - resource not found`.

When I change the `request(options)` method with `request("https://api.quickpay.net/payments")`, I get a positive answer from the server -- it tells me to add headers and so forth, which is positive.

```
    public requestNewQuickpayPayment(order_id: String, currency : String, callback: Function) {

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://api.quickpay.net/payments',
            form:{
                order_id : "order123",
                currency : "dkk"
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                'Accept-Version': 'v10'
              },
            json: true
        };
        request(options).then((response:any)=>{
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }).catch((error:any)=>{
            console.log(error);
            return error;
        }).finally(()=>{
            console.log("done");

        })
    }
```

Something from the console

```
      Request {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        uri: [Url],
        transform2xxOnly: true,
        headers: [Object],
        readable: true,
        writable: true,
        explicitMethod: true,
        _qs: [Querystring],
        _auth: [Auth],
        _oauth: [OAuth],
        _multipart: [Multipart],
        _redirect: [Redirect],
        _tunnel: [Tunnel],
        _rp_resolve: [Function],
        _rp_reject: [Function],
        _rp_promise: [Promise],
        _rp_callbackOrig: undefined,
        callback: [Function],
        _rp_options: [Object],
        setHeader: [Function],
        hasHeader: [Function],
        getHeader: [Function],
        removeHeader: [Function],
        localAddress: undefined,
        pool: {},
        dests: [],
        __isRequestRequest: true,
        _callback: [Function: RP$callback],
        proxy: null,
        tunnel: true,
        setHost: true,
        originalCookieHeader: undefined,
        _disableCookies: true,
        _jar: undefined,
        port: 443,
        host: 'api.quickpay.net',
        body: 'order_id=asdasdasd&currency=dkk',
        path: '/payments',
        _json: true,
        httpModule: [Object],
        agentClass: [Function],
        agent: [Agent],
        _started: true,
        href: 'https://api.quickpay.net/payments',
        req: [ClientRequest],
        ntick: true,
        response: [Circular],
        originalHost: 'api.quickpay.net',
        originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
        responseContent: [Circular],
        _destdata: true,
        _ended: true,
        _callbackCalled: true },
     toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
     caseless: Caseless { dict: [Object] },
     body: '404 Not Found' } }
```

What is wrong here? The path to the ressource is checked many times - nothing is wrong there....

Answer (score 0):

For `api.quickpay.net`, `404 Not Found` does not mean the URI is not recognized, but indicating invalid request body. It has nothing to do with whether the URI is stated in `options` object, or stated as string parameter of `request()`.

Here is a simple experiment. The code below would return "positive" result, warning missing headers (`{"error":"Accept-Version http header is required"}`), which indicates that the URI is "recognized":

```
request({
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://api.quickpay.net/payments'
}, function(err, res, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

However, after the missing `Accept-Version` header is added, we get `404 Not Found`:

```
request({
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'https://api.quickpay.net/payments',
  headers: {
    'Accept-Version': 'v10'
  }
}, function(err, res, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Thus, in order to make the API call work, you need to make the HTTP request valid (following to the [document](https://learn.quickpay.net/tech-talk/api/services/#payouts)).